# How can I open link generated by Dtale in python google colab notebook using NGROK

Tags: pandas, google-colaboratory, ngrok

I am facing a problem with opening the link generated after using Dtale library in pandas. When I click the link its showing following error

ERR_NGROK_6022
Before you can serve HTML content, you must sign up for a free ngrok account and install your authtoken.

I have install NGROK in my pc and also installed autotoken

Authtoken saved to configuration file: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local/ngrok/ngrok.yml

but it still not opening the link

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Comment: I am not well-versed with Dtale or ngrok, but how you checked this: https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?